# Error to upload files from databricks to adls with python

Tags: azure

Im trying to move a file into a Azure Datalake Storage with BlobServiceClient, the thing its that im having a problem i think with the format of the file im trying to move into the ADLS or with the path of the file, but i try this same code with the local path of my pc in visual studio and it works, finally move the file to de ADLS. I have a little time working with azure libraries in python and i dont know because this error appears, i hope somebody can help me

I pass a txt to csv with:
[image]

Then i use that csv to move it into ADLS:
[image]

Getting this error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> upload files from databricks to adls with python

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

Firstly i uploaded csv file into databricks like below:

- Firstly click on file then click on  Upload data to DBFS

[image]

Then browse in local pc:

[image]

Then:

[image]

Then I changed :

Copied Path `dbfs:/FileStore/shared_uploads/@micro/emo.csv` changed to `/dbfs/FileStore/shared_uploads/@micro/emo.csv`

Then executed below code:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient, __version__
import os

sk="storage account key"
sn="name of storage account"
cn="name of container"
sc="Connection string of Storage account"

bsc = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(sc)

fp = "/dbfs/FileStore/shared_uploads/@micro/emo.csv"
bn = "emo.csv"
bc = bsc.get_blob_client(container=cn, blob=bn)

with open(fp, "rb") as data:
    bc.upload_blob(data, overwrite=True)
```

[image]

Then File Uploaded :

[image]